# Extracting a string between specified characters in python

Tags: python, regex

I'm a newbie to regular expressions and I have the following string:

```
sequence = '["{\"First\":\"Belyuen,NT,0801\",\"Second\":\"Belyuen,NT,0801\"}","{\"First\":\"Larrakeyah,NT,0801\",\"Second\":\"Larrakeyah,NT,0801\"}"]'
```

I am trying to extract the text `Belyuen,NT,0801` and `Larrakeyah,NT,0801` in python. I have the following code which is not working:

```
re.search('\:\\"...\\', ''.join(sequence))
```

I.e. I want to get the string between characters `:\` and `\`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use regex for this. It appears to be a rather strangely split set of JSON strings. Join them back together and use the `json` module to decode it.

```
import json
sequence = '[%s]' % ','.join(sequence)
data = json.loads(sequence)
print data[0]['First'], data[0]['Second']
```

(Note the json module is new in Python2.6 - if you have a lower version, download and install simplejson).

Comment: the sequence is actually of string type (I updated question). the interpreter keeps throwing an error for the line `data = json.loads(sequence)` and the error is `raise ValueError(errmsg("Expecting object", s, end))`

Comment: if I scrap the second line of your code and print `data[0]` I get: `{"First":"Belyuen,NT,0801","Second":"Belyuen,NT,0801"}`

Comment: and if I print `data[0]['First']` it comes up with the following error: ` print data[0]['First'] TypeError: string indices must be integers`

Comment: I ended up being able to extract what I wanted by doing the following: ` data = json.loads(sequence) /n location = json.loads(data[0]) /n print location['First']`

Answer (score 3):

it seems like a proper serialization of the Python dict, you could just do:

```
>>> sequence = ["{\"First\":\"Belyuen,NT,0801\",\"Second\":\"Belyuen,NT,0801\"}","{\"First\":\"Larrakeyah,NT,0801\",\"Second\":\"Larrakeyah,NT,0801\"}"]
>>> import json
>>> for i in sequence:
    d = json.loads(i)
    print(d['First'])


Belyuen,NT,0801
Larrakeyah,NT,0801
```

Comment: the sequence is actually a string not list ( I updated the question ). so how do I load it into the json module as a string?

Comment: @seth: unfortunately, it seems that the quotes in your input string are misused. it doesn't work either with `json` or `eval`. If you fix them, using alternate single and double quote, escaped where needed, then it works just fine with the method I showed. Again, quotes within string should be alternating, quotes that were used for original Python string, should be, of course, escaped.

Comment: thanks for your response, check out my comments in Daniel Roseman's answer. I ended up extracting what I needed in a convoluted way, but got it nevertheless. +1 for your help and useful answer.

Answer (score 2):

you don't need regex

```
>>> sequence = ["{\"First\":\"Belyuen,NT,0801\",\"Second\":\"Belyuen,NT,0801\"}","{\"First\":\"Larrakeyah,NT,0801\",\"Second\":\"Larrakeyah,NT,0801\"}"]
>>> for item in sequence:
...  print eval(item).values()
...
['Belyuen,NT,0801', 'Belyuen,NT,0801']
['Larrakeyah,NT,0801', 'Larrakeyah,NT,0801']
```

Comment: solution works in version <2.6. And i don't want to download any other modules.